# is there a way to query a local rpm for information, like in yum info?

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, yum

I'd like to issue a command to query information about a local rpm package. Something like this:

```
yum localinfo mylocalrpmpackage.rpm
```

`yum info` just queries information about remote packages.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to do [this](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/sec-Displaying_Package_Information.html). Relevant options for `rpm` are: `-qi`. Where `q` means query and

> -i, --info
>       Display package information, including name, version, and description. This uses the --queryformat if one was specified.

For example `rpm -qi <file>`.

Comment: I had more luck with `rpm -qip <file>`, without the `p` it would simply say "package <file> is not installed"